# R - combine two character vectors, then cut off last character

Tags: r

I am handling a large data set which stores a 9-digit ID in two columns, say `ID_part_1` and `ID_part_2`

ID part 1 is a common identifier for top-level specification which are duplicated throughout this column and ID part 2 is unique for each ID part 1. I want to combine part 1 with part 2 and then cut off the last character or integer of the generated strings.

See the example data below:

```
    ID_part_1    ID_part_2    Comb_ID
    G12345       678          G1234567
    G12345       679          G1234567
    A23567       9C1          A235679C
    123456       789          12345678
```

All data is stored in a data.table, say `my_data.dt`, so the columns can be addressed easily. Both columns `ID_part_1` and `ID_part_2`  are of type "character". The computed results should be stored in column Comb_ID. As trimming the last character off the combined string, I will then subsequently extract all unique values from the computed column as:

```
unique(my_data.dt[, Comb_ID])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `substr` with `paste` in `base R`

```
my_data.dt$Comb_ID <- with(my_data.dt,
      paste0(ID_part_1, substr(ID_part_2, 1, 2)))

my_data.dt$Comb_ID
#[1] "G1234567" "G1234567" "A235679C" "12345678"
```

NOTE: No packages are needed

#### data

```
my_data.dt <- structure(list(ID_part_1 = c("G12345", "G12345", "A23567", "123456"
), ID_part_2 = c("678", "679", "9C1", "789"), Comb_ID = c("G1234567", 
"G1234567", "A235679C", "12345678")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option based in the tidyverse.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

data %>%
  mutate(Comb_ID = map2_chr(ID_part_1, ID_part_2, ~ str_c(.x, .y, collapse = '')),
         Comb_ID = str_sub(Comb_ID, 1, -2))


#    ID_part_1 ID_part_2  Comb_ID
# 1:    G12345       678 G1234567
# 2:    G12345       679 G1234567
# 3:    A23567       9C1 A235679C
# 4:    123456       789 12345678
```

Data

```
data <- structure(list(ID_part_1 = c("G12345", "G12345", "A23567", "123456"
), ID_part_2 = c("678", "679", "9C1", "789")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55dd6c5238e0>)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll benchmark both solutions and just choose the faster one! Appreciate it!

Comment: This will be slower I suspect, but only because of the looping in the `map2_chr`, which isn't necessary. `my_data.dt %>% mutate(Comb_ID = str_sub(str_c(ID_part_1, ID_part_2), 1, -2))` will work since the `str_*` functions are already vectorised.